# Chain rule for derivative of matrix-valued function

Tags: matrices, derivatives, partial-derivative

Hi I have the following problem:

Let $x=x(t),a\in R^2$ with scalar $t$ and $\dot x=\frac{dx}{dt}$. Let the matrix-valued function, $f$, be
$$f(x(t))=x(t)x(t)^T+Ie^{\|a-x\|^2},$$ with $I$ being the identity matrix.
What is the derivative $\frac{df(x)}{dt}$?

My best try for the first term so far is evaluating the matrix column-wise, similar to a vector-valued function:
$$\frac{dxx^T}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\begin{bmatrix}x_1^2&x_1x_2\\x_1x_2&x_2^2\end{bmatrix}\right)=\begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2x_1&0\\x_1&x_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{bmatrix}& \begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2\\0&2x_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}.$$

I am not sure if this is correct and how to differentiate the second term. Help is much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're slightly off for the derivative of the first term. Use the chain rule on each component to see that
$$\frac{d}{dt} xx^\intercal = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\begin{matrix} 
2x_1\dot x_1 & \dot x_1 x_2 + x_1 \dot x_2 \\
\dot x_1 x_2 + x_1 \dot x_2 & 2x_2\dot x_2
\end{matrix} 
\end{bmatrix}. $$

Factoring each column gives
$$ \begin{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}2x_1&0\\x_2&x_1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{bmatrix}& \begin{bmatrix}x_2&x_1\\0&2x_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dot x_1\\\dot x_2\end{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}, $$
which is very close to what you had. It is not clear to me why you would perform this factorization though. I prefer $$ \frac{d}{dt} xx^\intercal = \dot x x^\intercal + x \dot x^\intercal $$ as an alternative form.

Now the second term. Recall that $||a - x||^2 = (a_1 - x_1)^2 + (a_2 - x_2)^2$. Using the multivariate chain rule, $\frac{d}{dt} ||a - x||^2 = \dot x_1\frac{d}{dx_1} ||a - x||^2 + \dot x_2\frac{d}{dx_2} ||a - x||^2 = \dot x_1(2x_1 - 2a_1) + \dot x_1(2x_1 - 2a_1) = 2\dot x^\intercal (x - a).$

Then we can apply the chain rule again to get the derivative of the second term,

$$ \frac{d}{dt} I e^{||a - x||^2} = Ie^{||a - x||^2} \cdot 2\dot x^\intercal (x - a). $$

Comment: Thanks Frank, much appreciated, you saved my day. I would like to have it separated as an additional dimension for implementation purposes.